# file_get_contents speed-up

Tags: html, timeout, file-get-contents

I am building an rss feed discovery service by scraping a page URL and finding the `<link>` tags in the page header. The problem is some URLs take really long to serve the page source so my code gets stuck at `file_get_contents($url)` very often.

Is there a way to do this with a predefined timeout, for example if 10 seconds have passed and there is still no content served then simply drop that URL and move to the next one?

I was thinking to use the `maxLen` parameter to get only a part of the source (`<head>..</head>`) but I'm not sure if this would really stop after the received bytes are reached of would still require the full page load. The other issue with this is that I have no idea what value to set here because every page has different content in the `head` tag so sizes vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just been reading about this, so this is theory only right now.. but..

This is the function definition, notice the resource context part:

```
string file_get_contents ( string $filename [, bool $use_include_path = false [, **resource $context** [, int $offset = -1 [, int $maxlen ]]]] )
```

If you specify the result of a `stream_context_create()` function and pass *it* the timeout value in it's options array, it just might work.

```
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
```

Or you could create the stream and set it's timeout directly:

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php
```

Hope you have some success with it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'context' parameter. You can create a stream context by using the 'stream_context_create' function, and specifying in the http context the desired timeout.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => YOUR_TIMEOUT,
    )
));
$content = file_get_contents(SOME_FILE, false, $context);
```

More information:
[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) and [also here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)